# download files with tornado and assign names

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to use tornado to download files async from a list of servers and I'm having problems when naming the files for each download.
This is the code I'm working now with (all hosts is defined earlier and it's query from a DB):

```
http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

i=0

def download_file(host,ip):
    month = "01"
    year = "2016"
    url="http://" + ip + ":1055/data?mo=01&ye=2016"
    http_client.fetch(url, callback=write_file)
    global i
    i -= 1
    if i == 0:
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
    print "DONE"+host+year+month

def write_file(response, host,year,month):
    with open(host+"-tt-"+str(year)+"-tt-"+str(month)+"-tt-.csv", "w") as f:
       f.write(response.body)
       print "DONE"

for host in all_hosts:
    ip = host[1]
    host = host[0]
    http_client.fetch(download_file(host,ip))

ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I'm not sure how to handle the passing of variables to the write_file function through the callback, or even if this is the best way to do this.
Ideally I'd like the file named based on the hostname, which is not in the response or url.

Any ideas on how to do this correctly?

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 1):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Make `response` the last argument to `write_file` instead of the first and bind the other arguments like this:

http_client.fetch(url, callback=functools.partial(write_file, host, year, month))

Comment: nice, thanks, I'll try and let you know and mark as an answer :-)

Comment: Hi Ben, that worked, do you want to write it as answer?